# Erro ao tentar listar os funcionários na tela venda do projeto

Tags: html, jsf, view

Estou com seguinte erro ao acessar a tela de finalização de vendas, não mostra o funcionários cadastrados, porém os clientes mostram.

Screenshot:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

View:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    template="/templates/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="conteudo">

        <h:form id="formulario">

            <p:panel header="Produtos">

                <p:dataTable id="tabelaProduto"
                    emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado." paginator="true"
                    value="#{vendaController.produtos}" var="produto" rows="5"
                    paginatorPosition="bottom">



                    <p:column headerText="Descrição" filterBy="#{produto.descricao}"
                        sortBy="#{produto.descricao}">

                        <h:outputText value="#{produto.descricao}" />

                    </p:column>



                    <p:column headerText="Quantidade" sortBy="#{produto.quantidade}">

                        <h:outputText value="#{produto.quantidade}" />

                    </p:column>



                    <p:column headerText="Preço" sortBy="#{produto.preco}">

                        <h:outputText value="#{produto.preco}">

                            <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2" />

                        </h:outputText>

                    </p:column>



                    <p:column headerText="Fabricante"
                        filterBy="#{produto.fabricante.descricao}"
                        sortBy="#{produto.fabricante.descricao}">

                        <h:outputText value="#{produto.fabricante.descricao}" />

                    </p:column>



                    <p:column headerText="Opções">

                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus"
                            actionListener="#{vendaController.adicionar}"
                            update=":formulario:tabelaCesta :formulario:painelFinalizacao">

                            <f:attribute name="produtoSelecionado" value="#{produto}" />

                        </p:commandButton>

                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

            </p:panel>



            <p:panel header="Cesta de Compras">

                <p:dataTable id="tabelaCesta"
                    emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado." paginator="true"
                    value="#{vendaController.itensVenda}" var="itemVenda" rows="5"
                    paginatorPosition="bottom">



                    <p:column headerText="Descrição">

                        <h:outputText value="#{itemVenda.produto.descricao}" />

                    </p:column>



                    <p:column headerText="Preço Un.">

                        <h:outputText value="#{itemVenda.produto.preco}">

                            <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2" />

                        </h:outputText>

                    </p:column>



                    <p:column headerText="Qtde.">

                        <h:outputText value="#{itemVenda.quantidade}" />

                    </p:column>



                    <p:column headerText="Preço Parcial">

                        <h:outputText value="#{itemVenda.precoParcial}">

                            <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2" />

                        </h:outputText>

                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Opções">

                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-minus"
                            actionListener="#{vendaController.remover}"
                            update=":formulario:tabelaCesta :formulario:painelFinalizacao">

                            <f:attribute name="itemSelecionado" value="#{itemVenda}" />

                        </p:commandButton>

                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

            </p:panel>

            <p:panel header="Finalização">

                <h:panelGrid id="painelFinalizacao" columns="3">

                    <p:outputLabel value="Total: R$" />

                    <h:outputText value="#{vendaController.venda.precoTotal}">

                        <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2" />

                    </h:outputText>

                    <p:commandButton value="Finalizar"
                        actionListener="#{vendaController.finalizar}"
                        update=":mensagem :formularioFinalizar:painelFinalizar"
                        oncomplete="PF('dialogo').show();">

                        <f:actionListener
                            type="org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener" />

                    </p:commandButton>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>

        </h:form>

        <p:dialog header="Finalizar Venda" widgetVar="dialogo"
            draggable="false" resizable="false" modal="true" closable="false">

            <h:form id="formularioFinalizar">

                <h:panelGrid id="painelFinalizar" columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Horário: " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{vendaController.venda.horario}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" locale="pt_BR"
                            timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" />
                    </h:outputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Total: R$" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{vendaController.venda.precoTotal}">
                        <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2" />
                    </h:outputText>

                    <p:outputLabel for="funcionario" value="Funcionário:" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="funcionario"
                        value="#{vendaController.venda.funcionario}"
                        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" filter="true"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="O campo FUNCIONÁRIO é obrigatório">
                        <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true"
                            itemLabel="Selecione um funcionário" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{vendaController.funcionarios}"
                            var="funcionario" itemValue="#{funcionario}"
                            itemLabel="#{funcionario.pessoa.nome} - #{funcionario.pessoa.cpf}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel for="cliente" value="Cliente:" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="cliente"
                        value="#{vendaController.venda.cliente}"
                        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" filter="true"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="O campo CLIENTE é obrigatórios">
                        <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true"
                            itemLabel="Selecione um cliente" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{vendaController.clientes}" var="cliente"
                            itemValue="#{cliente}"
                            itemLabel="#{cliente.pessoa.nome} - #{cliente.pessoa.cpf}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:commandButton value="Salvar"
                        actionListener="#{vendaController.salvar}"
                        update=":mensagem :formulario:tabelaProduto :formulario:tabelaCesta :formulario:painelFinalizacao"
                        oncomplete="PF('dialogo').hide();" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Fechar" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').hide();" />
                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:form>

        </p:dialog>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Controller:

```java
public class VendaController implements Serializable {
    private Venda venda;

    private List<Produto> produtos;
    private List<ItemVenda> itensVenda;
    private List<Cliente> clientes;
    private List<Funcionario> funcionarios;

    public Venda getVenda() {
        return venda;
    }

    public void setVenda(Venda venda) {
        this.venda = venda;
    }

    public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
        return produtos;
    }

    public void setProdutos(List<Produto> produtos) {
        this.produtos = produtos;
    }

    public List<ItemVenda> getItensVenda() {
        return itensVenda;
    }

    public void setItensVenda(List<ItemVenda> itensVenda) {
        this.itensVenda = itensVenda;
    }

    public List<Cliente> getClientes() {
        return clientes;
    }

    public void setClientes(List<Cliente> clientes) {
        this.clientes = clientes;
    }

    public List<Funcionario> getFuncionarios() {
        return funcionarios;
    }

    public void setFuncionarios(List<Funcionario> funcionarios) {
        this.funcionarios = funcionarios;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void novo() {
        try {

            venda = new Venda();

            venda.setPrecoTotal(new BigDecimal("0.00"));

            ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();

            produtos = produtoDAO.listar("descricao");

            itensVenda = new ArrayList<>();

        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {

            Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar carregar a tela de vendas");

            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void adicionar(ActionEvent evento) {

        Produto produto = (Produto) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("produtoSelecionado");

        int achou = -1;

        for (int posicao = 0; posicao < itensVenda.size(); posicao++) {

            if (itensVenda.get(posicao).getProduto().equals(produto)) {

                achou = posicao;
            }
        }
        if (achou < 0) {

            ItemVenda itemVenda = new ItemVenda();

            itemVenda.setPrecoParcial(produto.getPreco());

            itemVenda.setProduto(produto);

            itemVenda.setQuantidade(new Short("1"));

            itensVenda.add(itemVenda);

        } else {

            ItemVenda itemVenda = itensVenda.get(achou);

            itemVenda.setQuantidade(new Short(itemVenda.getQuantidade() + 1 + ""));

            itemVenda.setPrecoParcial(produto.getPreco().multiply(new BigDecimal(itemVenda.getQuantidade())));
        }

        calcular();

    }

    public void remover(ActionEvent evento) {

        ItemVenda itemVenda = (ItemVenda) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("itemSelecionado");

        int achou = -1;

        for (int posicao = 0; posicao < itensVenda.size(); posicao++) {

            if (itensVenda.get(posicao).getProduto().equals(itemVenda.getProduto())) {

                achou = posicao;
            }
        }
        if (achou > -1) {

            itensVenda.remove(achou);
        }

        calcular();
    }

    public void calcular() {

        venda.setPrecoTotal(new BigDecimal("0.00"));

        for (int posicao = 0; posicao < itensVenda.size(); posicao++) {

            ItemVenda itemVenda = itensVenda.get(posicao);

            venda.setPrecoTotal(venda.getPrecoTotal().add(itemVenda.getPrecoParcial()));
        }
    }

    public void finalizar() {
        try {

            venda.setHorario(new Date());

            venda.setCliente(null);

            venda.setFuncionario(null);

            FuncionarioDAO funcionarioDAO = new FuncionarioDAO();

            funcionarios = funcionarioDAO.listarOrdenado();

            ClienteDAO clienteDAO = new ClienteDAO();

            clientes = clienteDAO.listarOrdenado();

        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {

            Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar finalizar a venda");

            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void salvar() {
        try {

            if (venda.getPrecoTotal().signum() == 0) {

                Messages.addGlobalError("Informe pelo menos um item para a venda");

                return;
            }
            VendaDAO vendaDAO = new VendaDAO();

            vendaDAO.salvar(venda, itensVenda);

            venda = new Venda();

            venda.setPrecoTotal(new BigDecimal("0.00"));

            ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();

            produtos = produtoDAO.listar("descricao");

            itensVenda = new ArrayList<>();

            Messages.addGlobalInfo("Venda realizada com sucesso");

        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {

            Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar a venda");

            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```java
public class Venda extends Codigo {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date horario;

    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 7, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal precoTotal;

    @ManyToOne
    private Cliente cliente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Funcionario funcionario;

    public Date getHorario() {
        return horario;
    }

    public void setHorario(Date horario) {
        this.horario = horario;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrecoTotal() {
        return precoTotal;
    }

    public void setPrecoTotal(BigDecimal precoTotal) {
        this.precoTotal = precoTotal;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public Funcionario getFuncionario() {
        return funcionario;
    }

    public void setFuncionario(Funcionario funcionario) {
        this.funcionario = funcionario;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que está acontecendo é que você não listou funcionários. Olha seus produtos estão sendo listados, certo? Porque você listou eles no seu método *novo()*

```
produtos = produtoDAO.listar("descricao");
```

Quando você chama funcionarios no selectItems da sua página

```
 <f:selectItems value="#{vendaController.funcionarios}"
     var="funcionario" itemValue="#{funcionario}"
     itemLabel="#{funcionario.pessoa.nome} - #{funcionario.pessoa.cpf}" />
```

Esta vindo vazio, pois não foi declarado o que funcionários teria que mostrar, não sei como esta seu repositório, mas acredito que você queira mostrar todos os funcionários, então você teria que fazer algo assim:

```
funcionarios = funcionarioDAO.listar();
```

Comment: no controller tem no public void finalizar, está tudo, é quando finaliza a compra que só aparece o cliente e a lista de funcionários cadastrados não estão, e no finalizar, está o funcionários = funcionarioDAO.listarOrdenado(); igual ao cliente, e quando vou em finalizar compra, o funcionário é o único que não mostra o cliente mostra, mesmo eu olhando o banco de dados e fazendo uma consulta mostra que o funcionário cadastrado.